# Move Custom Module from one set up to other in local host?

Tags: magento-1.9

My custom module (which override product controller) successfully run in my set up but when i moved it into in any set up . it will give an error like this.

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

> a:5:{i:0;s:745:"Error in file:
>   "/var/www/html/mage2016/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permission_variable' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE
>   `permission_variable` (
>         `variable_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Variable ID' ,
>         `variable_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'Config Path' ,
>         `is_allowed` bool NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Mark that config can be processed by filters' ,
>         PRIMARY KEY (`variable_id`, `variable_name`),
>         UNIQUE `UNQ_PERMISSION_VARIABLE_VARIABLE_NAME` (`variable_name`)
>       ) COMMENT='System variables that can be processed via content filter' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8
>   COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:954:"#0
>   /var/www/html/mage2016/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you ran the code already and the table was created on first run, however for some reason module wasn't installed completely.

And, now when you trying to run it again, magento trying to install the table again but it finds the table already and is unable to create new one.

**Solution**

Although I don't know what's your sql part (or any other part).

When you first run, it must have given you an error message or a report, from where you could fix the trouble.

But now, system wont run your sql again.

**I would suggest to delete the table from database directly.**

Run this query in database

```
DROP TABLE `permission_variable`
```

Because you are upgrading the module, which is why you also need to edit one more thing in database:

Go to 'core_resource' table and find your `module_setup`(is same as in your config.xml) and edit the `version` and `data_version` to older version, i.e. `1.6.1.`.

**Before doing all of these, please backup your database.

Then clear the cache or reload the url.

I doubt it will throw another error message, why it cannot complete installing module. You should check this error message for further investigation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your installer I recommend to add the following lines

```
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('permission_variable')};
");
```

that will drop existing table first, if module is not installed.